# Unite two properties into plain list c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to somehow get list which contains both customerid and sallerid in raw. Is it can be accomplished withiot using two selection and then Union, is there any shorthand for this. Code is given below:

```
public class Model
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public int SallerId { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<Model>
{
    new Model(),
    new Model()
};

var customerIds = list.Select(model => model.CustomerId);
var sallerIds = list.Select(model => model.SallerId);
var userIds = customerIds.Union(sallerIds);
```

How userIds can be got by one operation instead of three

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in one pipeline as follows:

```
var result = list.SelectMany(x => new int[] {x.CustomerId, x.SallerId})
                 .Distinct();
```

This essentially projects each object `CustermerId` and `SallerId` into an an array and then collapses the nested sequences and finally calls `Distinct` to remove duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from Aomine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53686080/3212610) does pretty much what you asked for. But maybe another approach to it could simplify your problem.

If you don't intend for your Model to be a POCO, then just add the method GetUserIds() to the Model class:

```
public List<int> GetUserIds()
{
    return new List<int> {CustomerId, SallerId};
}
```

This way you could get your userIds in the following way:

```
var userIds = list.Select(model => model.GetUserIds());
```